# Index into a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

Suppose I have a list containing 9 fields, and the 9th field is a string.

Then `print(line)` will print the entire line, `print(line[9])` will return something like:

```
1/0:.:PASS:90:204,90:201,88:48,39:-204,0,-90:-48,0,-39:14:9,5:5
```

but `print(line[9[0:1]])`

will return

```
  File "FileParser.py", line 9, in ?
    print(line[9[0:1]])
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

If I assign `line[9]` to a second var, then I can manipulate it like a string, but this seems like a silly extra step.

Is there a way to index directly into the string while still part of the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index it like this

```
line[9][0:1]
```

`line[9]` will get the actual string and you get the range of characters from that string.

When you do `line[9[0:1]]` you are trying to get the range of values from the number `9`, which is not possible. That is why your code fails.

Comment: thank you. sorry for such a low-level question.

Answer (score 1):

Since `line[9]` is a string, then you have to do

```
line[9][0:1]
```

Let's say `line[9] = "some string"`. Then you can manipulate it with

```
line[9][0:1]
```

which will be equivalent to

```
"some string"[0:1]
```